# Separate events for collapsible text and icon separately in jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, mobile, jquery-mobile

Is it possible to handle two different events in collapsibles? First for the collapsible text (already handled) and a second one for the icon that appears (simulating a button).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are only 3 events triggered by collapsible content ...

`create`, `collapse` and `expand`

[See here for the docs](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/content/content-collapsible-events.html)

So you cannot trigger a different event for the icon. The only way you could do this is to implement the collapsible content your self - then use the `click` event.

Comment: Ok that was the way i did it: Normally in the jqm docs they provide examples such as <h2>header</h2>. And this worked for me <h2>header<a href="#" data-role="button">text for button</a></h2>